# Emails sent from localhost with nodemailer are not delivered

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

I've set up an email sending like this:

```
        nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
...
            nodemailer.SMTP = {
                host: 'smtp.gmail.com', // required
                port: 465, // optional, defaults to 25 or 465
                domain: 'smtp.gmail.com', // domain used by client to identify itself to server
                authentication: 'login', // optional, false by default
                user: '1*******@gmail.com', // used only when use_authentication is true
                pass: '*******'  // used only when use_authentication is true
            }

            // send an e-mail
            nodemailer.send_mail(
                // e-mail options
                {
                    sender: '1*******@gmail.com',
                    to:'2*******@gmail.com',
                    subject:'Hello!',
                    html: '<p><b>Hi,</b> how are you doing?</p>',
                    body:'Hi, how are you doing?'
                },
                // callback function
                function(error, success){
                    console.log('Message ' + success ? 'sent' : 'failed');
                }
```

Callback function logs "sent" but email is never delivered. I followed this tutorial http://www.thihaz.com/?p=218

Do I have to setup smth additionally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can let `nodemailer` take care of the corresponding server, Gmail for example:

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    auth: {
        user: "gmail.user@gmail.com", // service is detected from the username
        pass: "userpass"
    }
});
```

and then do:

```
transport.sendMail()
```

This should get you in the right path.

Comment: Are there any plugins to send mail while in development to test in a browser, such as mailcatcher for rails?

Comment: @TheJKFever [MailDev](http://danfarrelly.nyc/MailDev) is the closest thing I found to MailCatcher or Letter Opener.